# Why is Access-Control-Allow-Origin not in the response headers?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I tested with Advanced REST client (chrome extension) and ncat, but no Access-Control-Allow-Origin is present.
I launched first with the command line with various syntaxes and parameters for `--rpccorsdomain`.
Then I tried within the ipc console things like `admin.startRPC("0.0.0.0",  8545, "*")` (or other domains).

Anyway, this is my test request :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

HOST: rpc.wesen.fr:8545
content-type: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip
content-length: 58

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_mining","params":[],"id":1}
```

And the response headers :

```
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Origin
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2016 22:23:52 GMT
Content-Length: 39
```

with the data :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":true}
```

which is correct.

This is my configuration : 
(linux is arch)

```
Geth
Version: 1.5.4-stable
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.7.3
OS: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go
```

Comment: I posted an issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3422

Answer (score 5, accepted):

such header exists :

run geth with specific domaine `--rpccorsdomain "test.com"` or with '*'

then try

```
 curl -D - -H 'Origin: test.com' http://localhost:8545
```

you'll get :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: test.com
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Origin
Date: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 09:56:06 GMT
Content-Length: 58

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}
```

if you make an error in the origin you will not get an indication of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

for more detail look into the [go code](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/922c1f8f9f7763948da6ed755abd6e1fcaca2cac/rpc/http.go) , `func newCorsHandler(srv *Server, corsString string)` where allowedOrigins is defined.

Comment: Thank you ! I did read the go code, but did not try to send an Origin header. I do not understand why the host one is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to find a solution quickly, and I already was using ncat to serve over SSL, there is a hotfix (I removed the options about https, but it works with SSL since I only modify the output of the wrapped command with sed):

```
sudo ncat -lk -p 443 --sh-exec "ncat 127.0.0.1 8545 | sed -u '/^Date: /aAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *'"
```

(if you use another port, you won't need to sudo)

If you are not familiar with GNU sed, `-u` is the unbuffered mode to avoid latency, and the command just adds a line with the CORS policy after the `Date:` header. In the general case, you should use `'0,/^Date: /aAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *'` to replace only the first occurence, but here geth will never begin another line with `Date:`.

Obviously you can use any other domain or list of domains.
I hope this will be useful, but I do not consider it a valid answer to the question which is "why?".